# SQL using CASE in count and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm using `CASE` to categorize data in the table and count them but the results aren't accurate

live demo [[here]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1f44/8)

```
select DATE(date) as day, count(*),
count(distinct case when name = 'fruit' then 1 else 0 end) as fruits,
count(distinct case when name = 'vege' then 1 else 0 end) as vege,
count(distinct case when name = 'sweets' then 1 else 0 end) as sweets
from food
group by day
with rollup
```

I'm not sure if the issue is with `CASE` or in the string matching `=` because there's no 'sweets' still it counts 1?
any pointers I'd be grateful

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your problem is that `COUNT` counts every result that is not `NULL`. In your case you are using:

```
COUNT(distinct case when name = 'sweets' then 1 else 0 end)
```

So, when the name is not `sweets`, it counts the `0`. Furthermore, since you are using `DISTINCT`, it counts just one or two values. You should either use `SUM` or remove the `DISTINCT` and the `ELSE 0`:

```
SELECT  DATE(date) as day, 
        COUNT(*),
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'fruit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as fruits,
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'vege' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as vege,
        SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'sweets' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sweets
FROM food
GROUP BY DAY
WITH ROLLUP
```

Or:

```
SELECT  DATE(date) as day, 
        COUNT(*),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN name = 'fruit' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as fruits,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN name = 'vege' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as vege,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN name = 'sweets' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as sweets
FROM food
GROUP BY DAY
WITH ROLLUP
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1f44/10) a modified sqlfiddle.

Comment: ah! yes! makes sense :) accepting in 6 minutes .. thank you a lot

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue with understanding COUNT().

Answer (score 2):

You can't group by an alias.  You have to group by the expression.

```
group by date(date)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can group on an Alias:

```
SELECT 
     FROM_UNIXTIME(UnixTimeField, '%Y') AS 'Year'
     ,FROM_UNIXTIME(UnixTimeField, '%m') AS 'Month'

FROM table p

GROUP BY  Year, Month
```